# SqlBuilder where clause for "IN" operator throws exception for comma separated

Tags: c#, servicestack, npgsql, ormlite-servicestack

I'm adding a where clause to SqlBuilder that contains a "IN" operator and then assigning the parameter to a comma separated list of numbers. However, when select is called I get a PosgresException of {"42883: operator does not exist: integer = text"}.

```
SqlBuilder countBuilder = new SqlBuilder();
SqlBuilder.Template countTemplate = countBuilder.AddTemplate("select * from table /**where**/");

countBuilder.Where("id in (@ids)", new {ids = "1,2,3" });
var count = Db.Select<int>(countTemplate.RawSql, countTemplate.Parameters);
```

Comment: `"1,2,3"` is a `String`. A 'list' of numbers would be something like `[1,2,3]` or `new int[] {1,2,3}`, perhaps.

Comment: You can't add values to an `IN` clause via a parameter.  You'd have to concatenate the strings, which could open you up to injection attacks, or use a function that splits a string value.